# Display subscription in email

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, ampscript, subscriber

I want to pull a subscriber's list of subscriptions into a re-engagement email sent via Marketing Cloud.

e.g.

Hi

You are subscribed to:

1. xx
2. xx
3. xx

How do I pull this information through into the email dynamically using AmpScript?

Thanks

Josh

Answer (score 0):

Probably your subscribers would be inside the _ListSubscribers where the different names of the Subscription Lists could be gotten via AMPScript LookUpRows.

For that you would do something like (not 100% sure):

```
var @var1, @rows, @subscriberlist, @rowcount
set @var1 = [DataExtensionField that is your subscriberkey / id / emailaddress]

set @rows = LookupRows('_ListSubscribers','SubscriberKey',v(@var1),'Status','active')
set @rowcount = rowcount(@rows)

if @rowcount > 0 then
    for @i = 1 to @rowcount do
        set @row = row(@rows,@i)
        set @subscriberlist = field(@row,"ListName")

        output(concat("<br>",v(@subscriberlist)))
    next @i
else
   ???
endif
```

Comment: I would not recommend doing a lookup against the `_ListSubscribers` data view in the email.  It'd be much better to build a DE ahead of time and just do a simple lookup and loop in your email -- especially for a re-engagement campaign.

Comment: Indeed querying against `_ListSubscribers` will take a lot of time. Therefore you should create an automation in automation studio with an sql query that lists every subscription of subscribers which has the status active. SubscriberKey/ID should be the unique value in that dataextension and you should insert all Lists in a second field. Or something similar like that. And then you would query this newly created dataextension with a lookup. But if you wanna do that you need to have atleast the pro version of marketing cloud, if you have the basic edition you wont have access to automations.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick - you might want to update your answer for easier reference of other users instead of adding the details into a comment.